# Get a range of singular values from a sparse matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra

I have a huge sparse matrix with `3e5x3e5` dimension. I want to calculate its svd and I need all singular values. The implementation of `scipy.sparse.linalg.svds` will not work since it requires to allocate a full matrix with the same dimension as the sparse matrix. Is there a way to do this efficiently? If not, I am thinking to get the singular values sequentially such as:

```
#A is the sparse matrix. l is how many singular values are calculated in each iteration.n is dim(A)
i=0
while i < n:
  # it will give you, the ith to (i+l)th largest/smallest singular values. 
  get_range_of_singular_values(A,i,i+l)
  i = i + l
```

But I am not aware of an API that supports it? Any leads on how to solve this problem?  I also need the singular vectors so if the solution does not provide them that wouldn't be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your options here are pretty limited and [TruncatedSVD](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html) is your best bet. This is one of the best options for SVD on a sparse matrix, but you can't recenter (for obvious reasons).

```
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD

# Use a 3e5 x 3e5 arbitrary CSR array
>>> arr
<300000x300000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 90000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>


# 5 components 
tsvd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=5).fit(arr)

>>> tsvd.singular_values_
array([2.01028547, 1.71143827, 1.66276059, 1.63698292, 1.61189899])
```

If you intend to use this for any analysis you should **at least** rescale the column variances to 1 to keep wildly differently scaled columns from driving the entirety of your output.